# EntityManager Lookup on CMT

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

I have a doubt a long time and never find the answer, so I appreciate any king of help or explanation... maybe it´s is just a conceptual mistake...

I have an environment where I use CMT and Hibernate. I can inject the EntityManager as a resource on my EJB without any problem. But I couldn´t make it inject direct in my DAOs, since I instantiate it with a traditional factory pattern....

But my question is: I need to use the EntityManager, but don´t want to pass it all the way down through my layers! Must have another way and I´m probably not seeing the solution...

Can I do some king of context lookup for this EntityManager? Or any other more elegant solution?

I made my own solution, but its kind of crap lol... don´t worth a discution...

Thanks for any help and sorry for any english mistake, it´s not my native language.

Comment: Why don't you simply implement DAOs as stateless EJBs?

Comment: Hi JB, thanks for your reply. Could be an idea, maybe easier than what I have in mind, since doing a lookup for the entitymanger will probably have a similar processing cost... I´ll take your idea thanks again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even following the JBNizet sugestion, I still curious to know how to get the EntityManager and I found this answer in how to lookup for the EntityManager on J2EE/EJB environment.

First, you need to put a @PersistentContext on the class scope of your EJB to set a def for later lookup and define the "name" attribute. Like:

```
@PersistenceContext(
name="myEntityManagerJNDIName",
unitName=InventoryManagement  // defined in a persistence.xml file
)
@Stateless
public class InventoryManagerBean implements InventoryManager { ... }
```

Then you can lookup for your EntityManager with a code like this:

```
...
// obtain the initial JNDI context
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
// perform JNDI lookup to obtain container-managed entity manager
javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager = (javax.persistence.EntityManager) 
   initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/myEntityManagerJNDIName");
...
```

That is the way I found to get the EntityManager without injections.